# How can i display the ordered list generated from database value in one line ?

Tags: html, css

In the below php code, am fetching the list of items bought from database. since its stored as comma separated values am exploding it and fetching in while loop. as an output i get ordered list of items bought.. 
but i want the ordered list to be displayed horizontally.

Now the output is like this:

Items Bought

1. Coffee Maker
2. Washing Machine

For example the output should be:

Items Bought: 1) Coffee Maker 2) Washing Machine

Please help me how can i do that by list or anything to get this kind of output.

```
<?
    echo "<strong>Items Bought:</strong>";
        echo "<ol>";
                    $q=mysql_query("select * from lead where id='$ID'");
                    $rs=mysql_fetch_object($q);
                    $prod_interest = $rs->interested_in;
                    $prod_name = explode(",", $prod_interest);

                    $pname='';
                    for($i = 0; $i < count($prod_name); $i++){

                    $prd_name= $prod_name[$i];
                    //taking the product name for the id
                    $productname=mysql_query("select * from product where id='$prd_name'");

                    while ($prow=mysql_fetch_object($productname))
                    {
                ?>
                <li value="<? echo $pname=$prow->id;?>"><? echo $pname=$prow->name;?></li>
                <?
                        }
                    }
                    echo "</ol>";
                ?>
```

Comment: Would the ordered list not produce a vertical list automatically? That can then be styled by css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this problem is more of an HTML issue, your LIs are probably floated and thats why you get a right to left list...

EDIT:

OH, then you want to add this style to your page:

```
<style>
ol li {
    float: left;
}
</style>
```

EDIT 2:

```
<style>
ol li {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    display: block;
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Nope am getting a normal vertical ordered list. I want that to be displayed horizontal..hope u got me rite this time.!

Comment: I think i'm not the only one who understood you wrong, we all understood you had something horizontal and wanted vertical, look at all comments and answers :P I fixed it, look at my edit

Comment: it works as horizontal mathieu...but its without numbers..i want it to display like 1)Item1 2)Item2.... now its displaying like Item1Item2Item3

Comment: I wish i could have spacings too..i tried everything but not working..:( am not proficient with css though

Comment: Its working Mathieu...thanks for your help...but i dont know why am not getting numbers

Comment: Hummm, maybe the list-type was reset in another CSS? Try "list-style-type: decimal;"

Comment: sadly...its nt working....i think it will be easier if we try something with php..as kaii said, without using lists...as per his suggestion the values are coming. I dont even want the prod_id to get displayed. i just want product name. so we just need that 1,2,3 numbering in the place of prod_id in the php code

Answer (score 1):

this is an HTML/CSS not PHP question. Using `<ol>` and `<li>` you get a list that is ordered vertically.. eg:

1. item 1
2. item 2

When you want them horizontally, you can either

**use CSS to convert the block `<li>` elements into an inline element:**

```
echo '<ol>';
while ($prow=mysql_fetch_object($productname)) {
  echo '<li style="display: inline">';
  echo $prow->id . ' ' . $prow->name;
  echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ol>';
```

**do not use a list at all:**

```
while ($prow=mysql_fetch_object($productname)) {
  echo $prow->id . ' ' . $prow->name . ' ';
}
```

Comment: hmmm...nice idea Kaai...but i dont want the product id to be in the first row. i want 1,2,3 numbering as per the number of products..

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a CSS issue than a PHP one. By default the list should show vertically unless you have reset.css or similar that is "resetting" the behavior of lists.

If you want to make sure that it prints a vertical ordered list, do this:

```
<ol class="vertical_ol">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ol>
```

In your CSS put this:

```
.vertical_ol li {
    display:block;
    float:none;
}
```